# Reading RDD with the header and filtering it

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am using the code below to load all the log file into a RDD.

```
logs_rdd = sc.textFile('/user/jovyan/weblogs/')
```

If I look at the first 10 rows with

```
logs_rdd.take(10)
```

It is giving me this output

```
['3.94.78.5 - 69827 [15/Sep/2013:23:58:36 +0100] "GET /KBDOC-00033.html HTTP/1.0" 200 14417 "http://www.loudacre.com"  "Loudacre Mobile Browser iFruit 1"',
 '3.94.78.5 - 69827 [15/Sep/2013:23:58:36 +0100] "GET /theme.css HTTP/1.0" 200 3576 "http://www.loudacre.com"  "Loudacre Mobile Browser iFruit 1"',
 '19.38.140.62 - 21475 [15/Sep/2013:23:58:34 +0100] "GET /KBDOC-00277.html HTTP/1.0" 200 15517 "http://www.loudacre.com"  "Loudacre Mobile Browser Ronin S1"',
 '19.38.140.62 - 21475 [15/Sep/2013:23:58:34 +0100] "GET /theme.css HTTP/1.0" 200 13353 "http://www.loudacre.com"  "Loudacre Mobile Browser Ronin S1"',
 '129.133.56.105 - 2489 [15/Sep/2013:23:58:34 +0100] "GET /KBDOC-00033.html HTTP/1.0" 200 10590 "http://www.loudacre.com"  "Loudacre Mobile Browser Sorrento F00L"',
 '129.133.56.105 - 2489 [15/Sep/2013:23:58:34 +0100] "GET /theme.css HTTP/1.0" 200 12295 "http://www.loudacre.com"  "Loudacre Mobile Browser Sorrento F00L"',
 '217.150.149.167 - 4712 [15/Sep/2013:23:56:06 +0100] "GET /ronin_s4_sales.html HTTP/1.0" 200 845 "http://www.loudacre.com"  "Loudacre Mobile Browser MeeToo 1.0"',
 '217.150.149.167 - 4712 [15/Sep/2013:23:56:06 +0100] "GET /theme.css HTTP/1.0" 200 738 "http://www.loudacre.com"  "Loudacre Mobile Browser MeeToo 1.0"',
 '217.150.149.167 - 4712 [15/Sep/2013:23:56:06 +0100] "GET /code.js HTTP/1.0" 200 938 "http://www.loudacre.com"  "Loudacre Mobile Browser MeeToo 1.0"',
 '217.150.149.167 - 4712 [15/Sep/2013:23:56:06 +0100] "GET /ronin_s4.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 5552 "http://www.loudacre.com"  "Loudacre Mobile Browser MeeToo 1.0"']
```

The question is I want to Filter out the requests for jpg files into a new RDD. You can see the last line of the output where the GET request start. I am confused whether there is a header I did not load or do I have to create a schema for the RDD and then filter the RDD. Anything would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using rdd i would recommend to use DataFrame as it is easy to process data with Header(column name)

Since your Data does not have schema/Header so when you load Data in a Dataframe it will automatically create a header for your data

> > > df.show(truncate=False)
> > > +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> > > |value                                                                                                                                                               |
> > > +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> > > |'3.94.78.5 - 69827 [15/Sep/2013:23:58:36 +0100] "GET /KBDOC-00033.html HTTP/1.0" 200 14417 "http://www.loudacre.com"  "Loudacre Mobile Browser iFruit 1"',          |
> > > | '3.94.78.5 - 69827 [15/Sep/2013:23:58:36 +0100] "GET /theme.css HTTP/1.0" 200 3576 "http://www.loudacre.com"  "Loudacre Mobile Browser iFruit 1"',                 |
> > > | '19.38.140.62 - 21475 [15/Sep/2013:23:58:34 +0100] "GET /KBDOC-00277.html HTTP/1.0" 200 15517 "http://www.loudacre.com"  "Loudacre Mobile Browser Ronin S1"',      |
> > > | '19.38.140.62 - 21475 [15/Sep/2013:23:58:34 +0100] "GET /theme.css HTTP/1.0" 200 13353 "http://www.loudacre.com"  "Loudacre Mobile Browser Ronin S1"',             |
> > > | '129.133.56.105 - 2489 [15/Sep/2013:23:58:34 +0100] "GET /KBDOC-00033.html HTTP/1.0" 200 10590 "http://www.loudacre.com"  "Loudacre Mobile Browser Sorrento F00L"',|
> > > | '129.133.56.105 - 2489 [15/Sep/2013:23:58:34 +0100] "GET /theme.css HTTP/1.0" 200 12295 "http://www.loudacre.com"  "Loudacre Mobile Browser Sorrento F00L"',       |
> > > | '217.150.149.167 - 4712 [15/Sep/2013:23:56:06 +0100] "GET /ronin_s4_sales.html HTTP/1.0" 200 845 "http://www.loudacre.com"  "Loudacre Mobile Browser MeeToo 1.0"', |
> > > | '217.150.149.167 - 4712 [15/Sep/2013:23:56:06 +0100] "GET /theme.css HTTP/1.0" 200 738 "http://www.loudacre.com"  "Loudacre Mobile Browser MeeToo 1.0"',           |
> > > | '217.150.149.167 - 4712 [15/Sep/2013:23:56:06 +0100] "GET /code.js HTTP/1.0" 200 938 "http://www.loudacre.com"  "Loudacre Mobile Browser MeeToo 1.0"',             |
> > > | '217.150.149.167 - 4712 [15/Sep/2013:23:56:06 +0100] "GET /ronin_s4.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 5552 "http://www.loudacre.com"  "Loudacre Mobile Browser MeeToo 1.0"'        |
> > > +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

> > > df.printSchema()
> > > root
> > > |-- value: string (nullable = true)

df=spark.read.text("Path to text file")

df.filter(df.value.rlike('.jpg')).show(truncate=False)